# Got stuck in a probability theory problem

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-theory

Let $X_{n}$ be i.i.d. RV with density $f(x) = \frac{3}{x^4}$, if $x\geq 1$; $0$, otherwise. Let $S_{N} = \sum_{n=1}^{N} X_{n}$. Show that for each $a>\frac{3}{2}$, $\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} N^{2} P(S_{N}\geq aN) = \frac{1}{(a-\frac{3}{2})^{3}}$.

I have proved that
$\liminf_{N\rightarrow \infty} N^{2} P(S_{N}\geq aN) \geq \frac{1}{(a-\frac{3}{2})^{3}}$. I got stuck in the proof of $\limsup_{N\rightarrow \infty} N^{2} P(S_{N}\geq aN) \leq \frac{1}{(a-\frac{3}{2})^{3}}$. I have defined the following random variable $\bar{S}_{N} = \sum_{i=1}^{N} \bar{X}_{i}$, where, $\bar{X}_{i} = X_{i} 1_{X_{i}\leq C N}$, where $C$ is a constant. Thus, $P(S_{N} \geq aN) \leq P(S_{n} \neq \bar{S}_{n}) + P(\bar{S}_{N}\geq aN)$. Thus, $P(S_{N} \geq aN) \leq P(S_{N} \neq \bar{S}_{N}) + \frac{\mathbb{E}[\bar{S}_{N} - \mathbb{E} [\bar{S}_{N}] ]^{6}}{(a N - E[\bar{X}_{1} N] )^{6}}$. Now, evaluating the left side of the inequality, we get $N^{2} P(S_{N} \geq aN) \leq \frac{C^{3}}{(a-\frac{3}{2})^{6}} + \frac{1}{C^{3}}$. Now, if we put $C= (a-\frac{3}{2})$, we get $P(S_{N} \geq aN) \leq \frac{2}{(a-\frac{3}{2})^{3}}$. But I need to show that $P(S_{N} \geq aN) \leq \frac{1}{(a-\frac{3}{2})^{3}}$. This is where I got stuck. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Where are you stuck? What do you know about sums of i.i.d. random variables?

Comment: @karl I have updated my question with the steps that I have followed. And I mentioned where I got stuck exactly. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: @Karl have you tried using CLT to answer this question? I'm getting for large $n$$$P(S_n\geq an) \approx \int_{\sqrt{n}\left(\frac{2a-3}{\sqrt{3}}\right)}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(-x^2/2)\mathrm{d}x$$ Therefore, $$n^2P(S_n \geq an)\approx 0$$ when $a>3/2$ and $n$ is large, which apparently isn't correct.

Comment: @Matthew I have not tried CLT. But I have already proved the lim inf is lower bounded by $\frac{1}{(a-\frac{3}{2})^3}$ for $a>\frac{3}{2}$. And from CLT, I can argue that for any $\epsilon > 0$ and for large n, $|P(S_{n} \geq an) - Q(\frac{\sqrt{n}(2a - 3)}{\sqrt{3}}) | < \epsilon$,  I think this does not automatically imply that for any $\epsilon > 0$ and for large $n$, $n^{2} |P(S_{n} \geq an) - Q(\frac{\sqrt{n}(2a - 3)}{\sqrt{3}}) | < \epsilon$ is also true.

Comment: I totally agree with you. That is exactly the issue I ran into when I proceeded with this line of reasoning.